# Shared tinylog configuration with separate files for each application

Tags: java, tinylog

Can tinylog use the same configuration file for multiple applications (war's), but write the log based on the display-name in the web.xml?

Right now, all our web applications use log4j and share a configuration file. The log files are written with the following variable in the file name:

```
<RollingFile fileName="${web:servletContextName:-unknownContext}-${env:COMPUTERNAME:-unknownComputer}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" >
</RollingFile>
```

This means when our application has a display name of svc1234_FancyService and runs on SERVER001 then the log is named:

> svc1234_FancyServce-SERVER001.2022-01-04.log

Can this behaviour be replicated with tinylog 2.4+?

Answer (score 1):

**Same Configuration File**

You can place the tinylog configuration file anywhere on your file system and set the path via the system property `tinylog.configuration`. tinylog will automatically use the log file that is set in this system property. The system property `tinylog.configuration` can be set in your `web.xml` files or globally via your application or web server configuration. For example, the global configuration file for JBoss EAP and Wildfly is `standalone.xml`.

**Log File Path**

tinylog supports environment variables and date patterns by default. For the servlet context name, you will need a custom system property.

Example:

```
writer      = rolling file
writer.file = #{servlet.context.name:unknownContext}-${COMPUTERNAME:unknownComputer}.{date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log
```

Then, you can set the system property `servlet.context.name` in the `web.xml` files for example.

Comment: I'll have to reread the documentation. If the system property option isn't there, I'll try to put in a pull request to add it. Perhaps it is there and I assumed it only applied to properties set on the JVM with a -D flag.

Comment: Which application or web server are you using? Do you want to set the system properties in the global server configuration or in the web.xml for each WAR?

Comment: We are using Tomcat and generally set the log configuration location with a -D flag on the server, but would put the log file name in web.xml as a property.